# parse a multiline text with pyparsing

Tags: multiline, pyparsing

I would like to parse a multiline text file having a content as

```
    section1:
  key1 val1
  key2  val2

section2:
  val1
  val2
val3

section3:

section4:
 somevalue
```

The header of the sections (section1, section2, ...) are defined. The goal is to read the values **under** the different sections. I'm getting in trouble with using the pyparsing module over several lines (the real problem is much more complex than this simple example).

When I use the following code, the parser expects **on every line the full list of defined keywords**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pyparsing import Literal, ZeroOrMore, LineEnd, ParseException

FileSyntax = None

def Grammar():

    #section1:
    section1 = Literal("section1:").suppress() + ZeroOrMore(LineEnd())
    #section2:
    section2 = Literal("section2:").suppress() + ZeroOrMore(LineEnd())
    #section3:
    section3 = Literal("section3:").suppress() + ZeroOrMore(LineEnd())
    #section4:
    section4 = Literal("section4:").suppress() + ZeroOrMore(LineEnd())

    return section1 + section2 + section3 + section4


def parseFile(filename : str):

    global FileSyntax

    print("\nparse results:\n")

    try:

        TestFile = open(filename)
        testdata = "".join( TestFile.readlines())
        FileSyntax = Grammar() 
        FileSyntax.parseString(testdata)

    except ParseException as err:

        print(err.line)
        print(" "*(err.column-1) + "^")
        print("* " + str(err))       

    except Exception as e:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc(e)

parseFile("testdata.txt")
```

How can I make a stateful parsing (dependent on the different sections)? Thank you.

Comment: Is the indentation significant? Or did you make it wonky on purpose to show that it should not be used to identify sections?

Answer (score 0):

If you print out the grammar expression itself, you'll get something like:

```
{{{{Suppress:("section1:") [LineEnd]...} {Suppress:("section2:") [LineEnd]...}} {Suppress:("section3:") [LineEnd]...}} {Suppress:("section4:") [LineEnd]...}}
```

That is, you are parsing all the section headers, but not the body of the sections. So you are probably failing on the first line after 'section1:'.

Also, there is no need to call readlines() and then join everything back together. Just call `TestFile.read()`.  Or even better, `pathlib.Path(test_file_name).read_text()`